# Does the differentiation method always work for finding the minimum value of an expression?

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry, maxima-minima

I recently came across a question where the minimum value of the expression $\sin^2 (x) + 4 \csc^2 (x)$ was to be found.

Initially, I tried applying the AM-GM inequality and got the answer as $4$. However, I soon realised that for this to be true, $\sin x = \sqrt{2}$ (the numbers on which the AM-GM inequality is applied must be equal),which is not possible.

I differentiated the equation and still got the same answer.

However, the answer is given as $5$.

Can anyone please help with this question as well as my general doubt about differentiation.

P.S: I'm in eleventh grade so I do not know any advanced math.

Edit: After searching on the internet, I found out that $\sin x$ can be greater than one for complex inputs. So is the minimum value of 4 taking into account the complex inputs? And how do we find the minimum value for real inputs?

Comment: Ifgnore complex inputs, would be my advice. The “differentiation method” is usually only applied on real functions.

Comment: There is no guarantee (without more hypotheses) that a local optimum corresponds to a null derivative : look at the function $x^3$ at $0$.

Comment: @Lelouch Actually the guarantee you say does not exist is a very easy theorem: If $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is differentiable and has a local extremum at $x$ then $f'(x)=0$. I don't see what your point is about $x^3$; that does not have an extremum at the origin...

Comment: You need to look at higher order derivatives if you want a sufficient property for the existence of an optimum. Your theorem only gives sufficient properties. My point was that, very often, students tend to forget that a null derivative is only neccesary but not sufficient.

Comment: Right. If you'd said there was no guarantee that a critical point corresponds to an extremum that would be an important true fact.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=|\sin x|$, so that $0 \le u\le 1$, and you want the minimum of $u^2+\dfrac{4}{u^2} = \Big(\dfrac{2}{u}-u\Big)^2+4$. To minimise this, you want the least value of $\dfrac{2}{u}-u$ (which is definitely positive), so the greatest value of $u$, which is $1$, giving the minimum value of the expression as $5$. To see why the differentiation method fails, look at a graph of $u^2+\dfrac{4}{u^2}$ (e.g. on Desmos): you will see the minimum turning point at $u=\sqrt{2}$, but also the the minimum in the range $0 \le u\le 1$, which does not include that turning point. In general, for reasonably nice functions, the extrema are at turning points. or at end points of their domain of definition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Many times the roots of $f'(x)=0$ which are stationary points cannot be found by hand, as it may be an implicit equation.

At a critical point $f(x)$ may be discontinuous or non-differentiable but max of min may exists. For example $f(x)=5+|x-2|$, min exists at x=2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer